# How to prove a Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, triangle-inequality

Let $f:\,\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ defined via $f(x) = \frac{\|x\|^2}{w\cdot x}$, where $w\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is fixed and the dot denotes the inner product. I want to show (or disprove) that, for $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $w\cdot x_1>0$ and $w\cdot x_2>0$, the triangle inequality holds:
\begin{align*}
f(x_1+x_2)\leq f(x_1)+f(x_2).
\end{align*}

Unfornately, just using Cauchy Schwartz and the triangle inequality of the norm doesn't do the trick, so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for positive $a$, we have
$$a\| x_1\|^2 + \frac{1}{a}\|x_2 \|^2 \ge 2 \|x_1\| \| x_2\| \ge 2x_1\cdot x_2$$
Putting $a = \frac{w \cdot x_2}{w\cdot x_1}$, we get
$$(w \cdot x_2)f(x_1) + (w\cdot x_1)f(x_2) \ge 2x_1\cdot x_2 \tag{1}$$
Now note that
$$w\cdot (x_1+x_2)f(x_1+x_2) = \|x_1 +x_2 \|^2  =\| x_1\|^2 + \|x_2 \|^2 +2x_1\cdot x_2$$
$$= (w\cdot x_1)f(x_1) + (w\cdot x_2)f(x_2) + 2x_1 \cdot x_2 \tag{2} $$
From $(2)$ and $(1)$, we have
$$(w\cdot (x_1+x_2))f(x_1+x_2) \le  (w\cdot x_1)f(x_1) + (w\cdot x_2)f(x_2) + (w \cdot x_2)f(x_1) + (w\cdot x_1)f(x_2) =  \ (w\cdot(x_1+x_2))(f(x_1) +f(x_2))$$
It follows that $$f(x_1+x_2) \le f(x_1) +f(x_2) $$